# alternative of fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) in DB laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

i was using

```
$stmt = $pdo_object->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

now I am using in laravel

```
$results=DB::select($sql);
```

is there is need to fetch all method in laravel is yes what will be the syntax. 
Please Explain

Comment: $query = DB::table('yourTable')->get();

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$result = DB::table('table_name')->get();
```

Check this

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results

**Edit**

If you want to run raw query, you can use like this.

```
DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```

Comment: i cant use like this just because my query is very complex

Comment: Select r.LocationId ,LM.Name+'-'+LM.LocationCode as LocationName from User_Master u(nolock), UserRoleLoc_link r(nolock) left join Location_Master LM(nolock) 
     on r.LocationId = LM.LocationId
    Where r.UserId = u.UserId
    AND u.UserName = '$username' AND LM.Status = 1 AND
    (IsNull(NullIf('',''),'1')='1' Or r.LocationId = '') AND LM.isLocationOnline = 1
    Group by r.UserId, u.UserName, r.LocationId,u.Password,LM.Name,LM.LocationCode
    having COUNT(r.UserId) > 0
    Order By Count(r.UserId) DESC

Comment: @SanjogMittal use _DB::select(DB::raw($sql));_

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$query = DB::table('yourTable')->get();
```

You can also use this for same controller:

```
$query = DB::get();
```

**References:**

**[Laravel Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries)**

**[Laravel Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins)**